# mysql user password algorithm

Tags: mysql, algorithm, passwords

How to change the password algorithm to SHA2 for mysql user. Is there any configuration changes? I guess, currently the mysql password is stored in SHA1 format. Please assist.  I am not talking about the SHA2 function but when the user enters the password when he creates the mysql user.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL [docu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) states something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY 'new_password'
PASSWORD EXPIRE INTERVAL 180 DAY;
```

Where the important part for you is

```
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY <YOURSTRONGPASSWORD>
```

**UPDATE**

As written in this [post](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68478) of the MySQL bugtracker, you must consider the following two aspects:

- You have to be connected to your server via a TLS/SSL connection or an unencrypted connection that supports password exchange using an RSA key pair [1].
- The MySQL server must be configured with SSL [2].

[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sha256-pluggable-authentication.html

[2]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encrypted-connections.html

Comment: Hello, I created the user but I was unable to login because I got the  error message:    ERROR 2061 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'sha256_password' reported error: Authentication requires SSL encryption
Thomas

Comment: @KThomasK could you solve your problem? If so it would be nice to accept my answer and if not, please supply further information to help you.

Comment: David - I can't do this on the production server. Nevertheless, thanks for your update.  I will try it on some other server and check.